# spark streaming - each interval adds SQL tab in the UI

Tags: spark-streaming

I'm running a Spark Streaming application (1.6.2) and in the web UI I see that each interval adds a new SQL tab that contains the completed queries.

After running for a few days it fills the screen with this tabs...

I assume it happens because I'm converting the Rdd in the Dstream to Dataframe and run queries on it but it doesn't feel right that it looks like this[image]

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Spark 2? I had the same issue with 1.X, after upgrading everything works fine.

Comment: I actually tried spark 2.0 and downgraded back to 1.6 because I couldn't get a stable application when consuming from Kafka. I'll probably try to use structured streaming with Spark 2 but it will take some time to migrate

Answer (score 0):

o.k. I was an idiot...

Inside the dStream.foreachRDD I used sqlcontext like this:

```
dStream.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    ...
```

which means I'm creating a new sqlcontext each interval.
I should have written:

```
val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(streamingContext.sparkContext)
```